# Updating Edges through .NET API Creates @Version in Orientdb for same record

Tags: c#, .net, orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb-2.1

I am currently using OrientDB 2.2.3 with .NET OrientDB-Net.binary.Innov8tive.0.1.5 package.

When I fire a Update query for Edge from the Application the Edge gets saved as a newer version. So now there is a record with version 1 and version 2. E.g #12:0 and #12:1.

**I do not want to maintain the versions of the record. How should I do this using the API. Or is there a way to switch this concurrency feature off in OrientDB.**

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each record maintains its own version number that is incremented at every update. In optimistic transactions the version is checked in order to avoid conflicts at commit time. So the purpose of the @version property is to check if any update have been made between the time you fetched the object and when you updated it. For instance if in your code you fetch a product, you update its properties, in the meanwhile the object has changed in the database (another piece of code has updated it), then you save it : you are trying to update the object with the version 2, but it has the version 3 in database. 
This can help you to prevent concurrent access to your database.

Comment: Yes I understand the purpose of the concurrency though I need a way to turn it off! thanks